# Add my other email in CC for job application

Tags: professionalism, job-search, email

I've been using my personal email ID (like mail@example.com) to send job applications to recruiters because I want them to notice my personal website which links to my contributions to open source projects.

However, a recruiter told me that my email ended up in their Spam folder.

This might be because my mail server is currently hosted on a shared server.

Until I get a premium email service, is it a good idea to CC my other gmail address so the recruiter knows my alternate email ID? Or is it better to write it down in the email itself?

Comment: how exactly is ccing another address supposed to stop your email ending up in the spam folder?

Answer (score 6):

> Until then, is it a good idea to add my other gmail address in cc so
>   the recruiter know my alternate email ID ? Or is it better to write it
>   down in the email itself ?

Use whichever email address will consistently reach recipients without being marked as Spam.

An email address is a poor way to call attention to your personal website. If you think this site makes an important statement about your ability to perform the job, mention the site in your Cover Letter and explain why the recruiter should visit.

Answer (score 1):

**For future communication with this specific recruiter:**

Forward the conversation to (only) your other address and send any reply directly from there to the recruiter.

Or assume your future mails to that specific recruiter will not be flagged as spam and reply as normal (on the assumption that the recruiter either replied or marked it as not spam on their side, and the email client is smart enough to not mark it as spam again), but this seems a bit risky.

**In general:**

Just send the mail from the more reliable address, since CC'ing another address should not stop the email from going to spam in the first place.

---

Note that I didn't recommend CC'ing - it might look suspicious or they just won't pay much attention to it. There isn't much point to simply telling them your other address - either you want them to reply to the other address, in which case just send from there instead, or you don't want them to reply to the other address, in which case there isn't much point in bringing it up.

People don't pay all that much attention to the email address you're sending from, and I strongly doubt anyone would type the domain into a browser in hopes of getting to your personal website, especially not a recruiter who probably gets a ton of emails from job applicants.

It's much better to add it to your resume or mention it in the email itself. I'd recommend assuming they won't visit your site even if mentioned, and thus make sure all your best achievements appear on your resume or cover email / letter, while possibly just mentioning your website as a minor detail somewhere.